# Bluetooth doesn't work on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

So I just finished building my first PC (Ryzen 7 3700x, MSI B550 GAMING EDGE WIFI, Windows 10 64bit) everything about it went smoothly except for when I tried to connect my Beats Solo Pro to my computer.

At first, it would say the device is connected and plays audio. But when I put my headphones on the audio doesn't play at all with the exception of some very distorted static-like audio of the song I was trying to listen to, which happened every now and then.

Then, later on within that day, I connected to it again but this time all it said was just "connected". It didn't say connected audio after that or anything like that. When I put it on to see if there was any audio, nothing came out, not even the static every now and then. I checked to see if this problem was only with my Beats or if it had the same problem with my other Bluetooth headphones and the same issue persisted with my other devices.

I then checked if it was a problem with audio in general but when I plugged in a wired headset it worked perfectly. So then I tried updating my Bluetooth and audio drivers in the device manager, but it said that everything was already up to date. I then completely uninstalled them and then reinstalled them but that didn't work either. I then updated my bios to see if that would work but of course, that didn't work either. I then checked to see if it would show up in the playback and it doesn't show at all, even though it shows up in the device manager. It also doesn't show up in the manage sound devices section of settings either.

Comment: Bluetooth certainly works in Windows 10. Try a different card for the card that contains your Bluetooth hardware.

Answer (score 1):

1.Make sure your Bluetooth device is in range. If your Bluetooth device is unresponsive or sluggish, check to make sure it’s not too close to any other USB device that’s plugged into a USB 3.0 port. Unshielded USB devices can sometimes interfere with Bluetooth connections.

2.If your device displays as Paired but you can’t hear audio, make sure it’s connected. Click Start-->Settings-->Devices-->Bluetooth & other devices--> Bluetooth-->device--> connect.

3.Have you tried the steps listed in the Fix Bluetooth problems in Windows 10? To narrow down the issue, you could also test by other wireless devices.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-bluetooth-problems-in-windows-10-723e092f-03fa-858b-5c80-131ec3fba75c

Answer (score 0):

You may have a defective Bluetooth module on your board, especially since you said you have the same problem with your other devices.

A cost-effective thing you could try is to purchase a USB Bluetooth dongle (they are very cheap, usually under US$20) and see if that works. Your troubleshooting steps here were quite thorough, and I can't think of anything else you have not yet tried.

I'm almost certain this will solve the problem. Then you're left to decide if you're okay having a board with a messed up BT module and just using the USB from now on, or if you want to return it for repairs.